# Unable to get Epson EPOS printer listeners working to monitor status of printer

Tags: android, printing, epson

I am using an Epson TM-P80 printer that is connected to my Android 7 device using Epsons [Android SDK](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=61). The printer is connected through bluetooth and I can print from my app.

I am having trouble setting up the `setReceiveEventListener()`, `setConnectionEventListener()`, and `setStatusChangeEventListener()` listeners so that I can continuously monitor the status of the printer and display warnings for low battery, low paper, paper jam, cover open, disconnection etc.

Calling `connectPrinter()` (using a button for testing) will fire off the `onPtrStatusChange()` listener but *only once*. I expected `mPrinter.setInterval(1000);` to report back every second, but this isn't the case. `onConnection()` is never called. What am I doing wrong?

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, ReceiveListener, ConnectionListener, StatusChangeListener {

```
private Printer  mPrinter = null;

    private boolean connectPrinter() {

        boolean isBeginTransaction = false;
        if (mPrinter == null) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            //mPrinter.connect(mEditTarget.getText().toString(), Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
            mPrinter.connect("BT:00:01:03:AA:BB:CC", Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);

            // Register the Event Listners 
            mPrinter.setReceiveEventListener(this);
            mPrinter.setConnectionEventListener(this);
            mPrinter.setStatusChangeEventListener(this);

            // Start monitoring 
            mPrinter.startMonitor();
            mPrinter.setInterval(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           ShowMsg.showException(e, "connect", mContext);
           return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPtrStatusChange(Printer printer, int i) {
            // This is only called once
            System.out.println("onPtrStatusChange ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnection(Object o, int i) {
            // This is never outputted 
            System.out.println("onConnection");
        }

    }
}
```

You can view the SDK docs here [Epson EPos Android SDK docs](https://www.docdroid.net/GTIsqxv/epos-sdk-android-um-en-revh.pdf)

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm banging my head right now trying to solve the same problem :-(